# Create the [fstar] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

It seems, F* (Microsoft research public domain language addressing specification and verification aspects) is right on the main stream of current programming language evolution/science.

I tried various tags, expecting a tag for this new (meta) language already exists:

- F* (produces all tags with an "f" in it...)
- F-star (does not exist, also produces unrelated google-hits)
- Fstar (does not exist)

I do not seem to have the "create tags" privilege myself yet and even if I had I could not really make up my mind as to what the best tag-name would be for this.

Also, there are a couple of alternate projects going in similar directions (using dependent types and type kinds along with theorem proving technologies to create correct specifications / implementations, some also with code generation facilities for other languages, such as OCaml, F#, JavaScript, etc). Thus, along with the specific tag, maybe someone could come up with a tag summarizing those arising technologies.

Please comment and discuss on the following:

1. Create a tag for F*?
2. Top level tag - makes sense? What could it be?

For information on the language, see [Fstar main web site](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/fstar/)

Comment: For a second, I thought this was a suggestion to add a profanity tag...

Comment: If this tag is created, I vote for `f-star`

Comment: You do have the create tags privilege.. To create a tag, ask a question, and add the tag you want to create to it.

Comment: Tags don't exist until people ask questions about them.  We don't pre-create tags.